# TabHost не отображает заголовки вкладок

Tags: android-sdk, android

Пытаюсь создать 2 вкладки для виджета TabHost. Вкладки создаются, но они без названий:
[image: Без названия]

---

**Код**

```
package com.samples.tabhost;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabHostActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);       
        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

        spec.setContent(R.id.tabPage1);
        spec.setIndicator("Document 1");  // Указал название 1 вкладки
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tabPage2);
        spec.setIndicator("Document 2");  // Указал название 2 вкладки
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

---

Файл разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="62px">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/tabPage1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/tabPage2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не содержит ошибок. Я взял Skeleton App из примеров и заменил исходники примера вашими. Итог:

[image]

Как видно названия вкладок отображаются. Что еще приходит в голову?

1. Неподдерживаемые шрифты,
2. Неудачное разрешение,
3. Неудачные цвета.

Comment: В настройках avd тип дисплея указан WVGA800. 
Как узнать поддерживаются ли используемые шрифты? ОС Kubuntu 10.10

Comment: Первым делом попробуйте повторить мои шаги для avd на android 2.2, WQVGA 400, остальное - по умолчанию. Skeleton App из Android SDK.

Comment: С разрешением WQVGA 400 отображается корректно, спасибо. Видимо баг в эмуляторе ...
Можно ли сделать название вкладки повыше, а то оно, на мой взгляд, слишком прижато к низу?